# how to index an element that has been appended to a 1d numpy array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a problem that I've relentlessly tried to solve. I have a numpy array that I append values at the end (demonstated down below):

```
array = []
for (x, y, w, h) in e:
    wm = int(x + float(w / 2))
    hm = int(y + float(h / 2)) 
    array.append([numpy.float32(wm),numpy.float32(wh)])
return numpy.array(array)

#and it gives 
[200.90489, 100.39489] #the second last 
[288.0594, 30.0950] #last
#and so on..
```

I want to index `array[0][-2] - array[0][-1]` so I can find the difference between the second-last appended element in the first column (the `200.90489`) and the last appended element in the first column(the `288.0594`). 
I can index the column but I can't index the row since it's a 1d array, I've tried numerous ways to convert it to 2d but it doesn't work. I've tried `numpy.resize` and `numpy.reshape` but both didn't help at all.
How would I go about this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the shape and dtype?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation? It is incorrect now, and it is unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Have you tried converting it to a list? Such as : `list(array[0])[-2] - list(array[0])[-1])` ?

Comment: I think you swapped i and j. Did you mean array[-1][0]-array[-2][0]?

Comment: Your code sample is bad; we are left guessing as to what you intend and what was actually produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments:

- `array` is a keywork of numpy, you should probably not use it as a variable name. It would work, but it is not best practice.
- `return` is for the return value at the end of a function, you can not put it in a `for` loop (plus, even in a function, the loop would be interrupted at the first `return`)
- It looks like your result will be a 2D array, `array[i][j]` should work. But I think you swapped `i` and `j`.
- Not sure why you convert to numpy.array, it works already with lists.
- Lots of apparently unnecessary type casting: `float` => `int` => `numpy.float32`. I'll assume below you want a rounded integer.

So if I guessed correctly what you want to do, this should work:

```
my_array = []
for (x, y, w, h) in e:
    wm = int(x + w/2.)
    hm = int(y + h/2.) 
    my_array.append([wm, wh])

if len(my_array) >= 2:
    last_wm_diff = my_array[-1][0]-my_array[-2][0]
    last_hm_diff = my_array[-1][1]-my_array[-2][1]

# It will work the same if you convert to a numpy array:
my_array = numpy.array(my_array)

if my_array.shape[0] >= 2:
    last_wm_diff = my_array[-1][0]-my_array[-2][0]
    last_hm_diff = my_array[-1][1]-my_array[-2][1]
```

Comment: I don't think, that naming it `array` is a big problem; that's why namespaces exist

Comment: @user8408080 It's not a "problem" to name the variable `array`, but it could be confusing and could actually be a bug if using `from numpy import *`. So it is a bad idea. Note that the `from ... import *` is also bad, I'm not suggesting one should do that.

Comment: Although, with further testing, I did notice that there's something wrong. The `last_wm_diff=my_array[-1][0]-my_array[-2][0]` does not yield the same results as I intended. With further inspection, I noticed that my_array[-1][0], if the array is [[285 284]? [330 287]]  gives  330, so I think that instead of [-1][0] selecting the first col and last row(ex. 285) the [-1] selects "hm" so the last element( in this case hm) and then the [0] selects the first column. But I wanted the [-1][0] to select the last appended value[-1] from the first row[0] from wm, its shape is a [2,2] to clarify.

Comment: If `A = [[285, 284], [330, 287]]`, then `A[-1]` is `[330 287]` and `A[-1][0]` is `330`, nothing wrong with that. If you want another value, use another index.
"But I wanted the [-1][0] to select the last appended value[-1] from the first row[0]." Sorry, it does not work how you want. What you describe is `[0][-1]`, not `[-1][0]`.

Comment: You mean `A=[[24 32]? [43 67]]` or `A=[[24, 32], [43, 67]]`?

Comment: What's with the question mark in `A`? What is the type of `A`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your array has shape of (1,2)

Then try:

`np.append(array,[numpy.float32(wm),numpy.float32(wh)], axis=0)`

Comment: Why is `np.insert` better than a list append?  It doesn't  operate in-place.

Comment: True, then ensure you specify the axis parameter during the append.

Comment: List append doesn't take an axis parameter!  Or do you mean `np.append`?  I dislike that function with a passion.

Comment: Sorry for not responding, didn't see your answer. I did investigate your answer by making an array with shape of (1,2): `array=numpy.array([[0]*2 for x in range(1)])` then I did `numpy.append(array, [numpy.float32(wm),numpy.float32(hm)], axis=0)` but this fecthes the error ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions. The [numpy.float32(wm),numpy.float32(hm)] has a shape of (2,). So I reshaped it `numpy.reshape(numpy.array([wm,wh]),(-1,2)) so now it has (1,2).  Putting it together numpy.append(array,numpy.reshape(numpy.array([w,h]),(-1,2)), axis=0)`.

Comment: But numpy.append(array,numpy.reshape(numpy.array([w,h]),(-1,2)), axis=0) fecthes ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (2). Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!